# How to dissolve links and split by other links

Tags: qgis, splitting, network, dissolve, road

I am trying to aggregate road network segments by intersection using QGIS.
The blue route consists of 1000 links, and I want to aggregate this route into two segments.
Ex: first and second segments are above and below the brown line, respectively.

Therefore, I tried to use "dissolve" function to convert the blue route from multi-lines (links) to a single line.

Then, I used "split with lines" with dissolved blue route and gold route.

However, when I ran the split with lines function, the dissolved blue route returned as the original route which consist of 1000 links.

How can I resolve this issue?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide example data? Your workflow seems correct, but there may be minor mistakes we don't know of.

Comment: Providing sample data could also help. Maybe your data contains geometry errors, duplicate geometries or whatever that prevents a clean workflow.